# See if a variable is an array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do you check if a variable is an array in JavaScript ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript)
>   [What is the best way to check if an object is an array or not in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202841/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-if-an-object-is-an-array-or-not-in-javascript)

How can i tell if a javascript variable is an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From just yesterday: [What is the best way to check if an object is an array or not in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202841/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-if-an-object-is-an-array-or-not-in-javascript)