# Javascript Check Object for empty or null fields and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I've got an array that has a lot of objects and embedded arrays. I need to iterate through the entire array to see if anything is empty or null.  My problem is checking Arrays and whether or not the arrays return empty.  I keep getting object arrays and they are not null or undefined so get added in even if length is 0.  What I've got so far.

```
var progressCount = 0;
var progressKeyLength = progressBarCriteria.length;
for (var i = 0; i<progressKeyLength; i++){
  //I can find the arrays here but still not able to check length since they are actually object arrays.
  if(Array.isArray(progressBarCriteria[i])){
    console.log('array' + i);
  }
  if (progressBarCriteria[i] !== null && progressBarCriteria[i] !== ""){
    ++progressCount
  }
}


progressBarCritiria = [
   example1: "",
   example2: "asdasdas",
   example3: 233,
   example4: {asda: 1},
   example5: {asadasda: "asdasdA"},
   example6: "",
   example7: [],
   example8: [1, 12312],
   example9: [{1: "ad"}, {1: 12312}],
]
```

So 1, 6 and 7 should not be added to my count.

Comment: please add an example of the mentioned array.

Comment: "I can find the arrays here but still not able to check length since they are actually object arrays." I am just asking. What is an object array? If it is an array composed of objects, you should still be able to get its length.

Comment: Example added up in edit.

Comment: The code you posted would result in a syntax error. The syntax you're using to put items in `progessBarCriteria` is not correct. If you're trying to load the array with objects you'd need to wrap each of those items in curly brackets, for example `{ example1: "something", }`

Comment: `progressBarCritiria` is not a valid array.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to check the `length` or `null` value for an array, you can think about the **[Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) - [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)** value as follow:

```
if (Array.isArray(progressBarCriteria[i]) && progressBarCriteria[i].length) {
   // This is an array and is not empty.
}
```

- This `Array.isArray(progressBarCriteria[i])` checks if that value is an array.
- If this `progressBarCriteria[i].length` is `0` the boolean value will be `false`, ortherwise will be `true`.

Comment: This is the error I get when adding that 2nd part : Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string | boolean | Skill[] | { status: string; }[] | { title: string; }[] | { type: string; }[] |...'.
  Property 'length' does not exist on type 'true'.

Comment: @Kenzo That looks like a typescript error? Are you using typescript or flowtype for this?

Comment: I am using typescript. Wasn't sure if the logic was different. Sorry

Comment: It just means that while this solution should work perfectly fine at runtime, you'll get a compile time error (which you did). Since you're accessing the item with an index, typescript won't automatically narrow the type. To fix, pull the item into a separate variable, then use that in the if condition. EG, on the line before the if: `let current = progressBarCriteria[i];`, then in the if statement, use `current` instead. That will allow typescript to properly infer the type.

Comment: adding current actually solved it for me. I was able to use this to verify if it was an array or not and then check length.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function to do that. It is important to notice that in javascript arrays are objects. So you need to check for objects by `if (typeof arr === 'object' && !(arr instanceof Array))`. For more informations check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265922/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-not-an-array) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object).

```js
function recursive_array_chekc (arr) {

  //check if arr is an object
  if (typeof arr === 'object' && !(arr instanceof Array)) {
    
    //check if object empty
    if (Object.keys (arr).length === 0) {
    
      //do something if empty
      console.log ('this object is empty');
    
    } else {
    
      //check object properties recursivly
      for (var key in arr)
        if (arr.hasOwnProperty (key))
          recursive_array_chekc (arr[key])
    
    }
  
  } else
  if (Array.isArray (arr)) {
  
    //check if array is empty
    if (arr.length === 0) {
    
      //do something if empty
      console.log ('this array is empty');
    
    } else {
    
      //check array elements recursivly
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        recursive_array_chekc (arr[i])
    
    }
  
  }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to look at both answers and came up with this working solution. This is using Typescript so sorry for confusion.

```
for (var i = 0; i<progressKeyLength; i++){
  if (!(progressBarCriteria[i] instanceof Array)){
    if(progressBarCriteria[i] !== null && progressBarCriteria[i] !== "") {
        ++progressCount
    }
  } else {
    let current = progressBarCriteria[i];
    if (Array.isArray(current) && current.length !== 0){
      ++progressCount
    }
  }
}
```